# Can you currently get from Turkey to Egypt by ferry?

Tags: ferries, turkey, egypt, mediterranean

Since April 2012, [Anrusstrans](http://www.anrusstrans.ru/) is offering a ferry service between the Turkish port of Mersin, in the south east of the country, and Port Said, east of Alexandria on the Egyptian coast. Over at horizonsunlimited, for example [here](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/sahara-travel-forum/ferry-boat-between-egypt-turkey-63954), there is some chatter about the journey, as well as some personal accounts. However, the personal accounts differ significantly in the details and are very anecdotal.

So far, Anrusstrans has not responded to my emails, requesting information, nor has a handler in Mersin.

Who has the lowdown on this? How often and on what days does the ferry leave Mersin? How much does it cost for a foot passenger?
Interesting to others, how much does it cost to transport a motor bike? A car?

Comment: Best I can find is: [Ship 1](http://www.anrusstrans.com/shipping/ships/219/), [Ship 2](http://www.anrusstrans.ru/shipping/ships/19/), [Ferry Info](http://www.ferrylines.com/en/operators/operator-information/operatorinfo/ANRU/?no_cache=1)

Comment: :) Thanks. So... now... how much for getting rfrom Mersin to Port Said...? :)

Comment: So was this suspended sometime in 2012/2013?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. The turkey to Egypt ferry has never, to my knowledge, been consistently available to 'regular' people, though (as  opposed to for ferrying goods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not yet a full answer, but it's a start.

The ferry leaves Mersin once a week. But... as I write this (October 16, 2012), after having spoken to Anrusstrans, the ferry has not run for the 'past month' and will not run for 'at least another month'.

(I might have an opportunity to try them again in April 2013. Any updates in the meantime are most welcome.)