# Are there any ferries from Europe to Egypt?

Tags: bookings, ferries, egypt

Are there any ferries to Egypt from Italy, Turkey, Greece or any country from south Europe?

Comment: oddly enough google maps says you can take a ferry from Izmir to Alexandria but as the real answers point out there's no info on such a ferry to be found.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/turkey-to-egypt-by-ferry

Answer (score 17):

It's obviously impossible to prove a negative, but given that [AFerry do not currently list any Egyptian ports](http://www.aferry.co.uk/ferryports.htm) AND [The Man In Seat61 says "There are currently no ferries to Egypt"](http://www.seat61.com/Egypt.htm#London%20to%20Egypt%20by%20train%20+%20ferry) I would say that at the time of writing, the answer is **NO**.

Comment: Some negatives are possible to prove. If we narrow the scope to "regularly scheduled, public ferries" it wouldn't be hard to prove, simply by doing a survey of all Egyptian ports, and whether they service any such ferries. (That doesn't mean it would necessarily be possible to do this research online)

Answer (score 8):

Adding to @AakashM's answer, there seems to be no active passenger ferry from Europe to Egypt, but according to [ferry.co.uk](http://www.ferryto.co.uk/Egypt_Ferries.html):

> From Europe – There is now a brand new ferry from Venice to
>   Alexandria. Although schedules are yet to be published. the jouney[sic] should take approximately three days and will be the only Europe to Egypt ferry in operation.

Too bad it is not informed which company will operate this ferry and when will that happen.

Comment: Interesting, and one to keep an eye on, but unfortunately according to [this aferry page](http://www.aferry.co.uk/venice-alexandria-ferry.htm) *"Please note that because of the continuing dangerous situation in Syria that this route, Venice - Tartous - Alexandria, **has been suspended for the time being**. It is unknown when normal service will resume"*

Comment: 3 day journey, sounds more like a cruise than a traditional ferry.

Comment: @gerrit Agreed. But being the sole option, there's not much else to do, except than taking a plane.

Comment: It appears that the service only ran for about a year, 2010–2011.  See my answer for more details (it was too long to fit in a comment.)

Answer (score 5):

Based on what I've found, it appears that there was a ferry service that ran from Venice–Tartous–Alexandria–Venice from approximately May 2010–June 2011, at which time service was suspended due to the beginning of the Syrian Civil War.

- The beginning of service is cited [here.](http://www.alternativeegypt.com/Transport/Ferries-to-Egypt.html)  Note this text is almost exactly the same text as found by @gmauch (complete with typo), except with the addition of the start date and the URL for the company.  The website is, unfortunately, defunct.

  > There is now a brand new ferry set to sail its maiden voyage in May 2010 from Venice to Alexandria. Although schedules are yet to be published, the jouney should take approximately three days and will be the only Europe to Egypt ferry in operation. For more info see: http://www.visemarline.com/
- Another article [here](http://www.lloydslist.com/ll/sector/ship-operations/article6662.ece) cites May 20 as the date of the maiden voyage (though I can only see the beginning of the article without a subscription.)
- [A description of the service can be found here.](http://www.wuestenschiff.de/dateien/PresentazioneVisemarLinePasseggeri.pdf)  Also, [an account of the voyage can be found on TripAdvisor;](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1725258-i15087-k4112962-Visemar_One_ferry_to_Alexandria_Egypt-City_of_Venice_Veneto.html) it sounds slow & frustrating, even by ferry standards.  [Here's a more sympathetic account](http://www.janula.com/blog/blogmostra.php?cod=256) (in Italian.)
- [The service was suspended in June 2011](http://www.ship2shore.it/en/shipping/visemar-discontinues-the-service_44933.htm), though cargo service with a different ship appears to have continued for at least a few months thereafter.
- According to http://marinetraffic.com, the *Visemar One* (the original ship that ran the ferry service) now appears to be providing ferry service between Valencia and Palma de Mallorca (Spain.)